# Request.QueryString[] does not return my desired value

Tags: asp.net, http, url-encoding

I have the following URL: `/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=Default.aspx#/mydesign`

`Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` only returns `"Default.aspx"`.

Why doesn't it return `"Default.aspx#/mydesign"`?

Comment: Please select the answer as the Accepted answer if appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Because everything after the hash mark (#) is called a fragment, and per the HTTP spec, the fragment portion of the url is never sent to the server. You can check it in clientside JavaScript only.

Comment: Based on the nature of the sample URL, it looks like you might be rolling your own forms login. I would recommend that your authentication module use [Server.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) to set the parameter before redirecting the user to Login.aspx, and likewise, when accepting the POST to login.aspx, use [Server.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx) when redirecting back to whatever was passed into ReturnUrl.